# What is qBittorrent encryption mode?

Tags: encryption, bittorrent, qbittorrent

I have just installed qBittorrent and I found the option `Preferences > Encryption mode:`, that can be set to Allow, Require or Disable encryption. What does it do? If I don't use encryption, would other users in my LAN or my ISP or other subjects (apart from seeder I download from) be able to discover what I'm downloading or seeding?

### Update

I should make the question a bit clearer. If I set `Encryption mode:` to `Require encryption`, would it be possible for a third party (ISP, public WiFi provider and so on) to discover what I'm downloading or seeding targeting me *as a specific user* or *my specific internet access point* and not, e.g., downloading or seeding a certain file to see what other IPs are doing the same? If so, what is the difference in enabling the option against not enabling it?

I'm not looking for a way to prevent anyone from monitoring my bittorrent activity - I should be able to set up a VPN or proxy system (or at least to find out how to do that =)) if I need - I'm just trying to understand what the option actually *does*.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it do?

It will accept connections of that type. "Require" means you only connect to encrypted clients. "Allow" allows for both unencrypted and enforced encryption clients. "Disable" means encrypted connections are not accepted.

> If so, what is the difference in enabling the option against not enabling it?

That setting is about CONNECTING with other clients that either have or have not enabled encrypting.

> **Would it be possible** for a third party (ISP, public WiFi provider and so on) to discover what I'm downloading or seeding targeting me as a specific user or my specific internet access point and not, e.g., downloading or seeding a certain file to see what other IPs are doing the same

Yes. Mind the bold bit. An ISP can always see what your IP is, what site you linked to and what you clicked so it does not matter if you encrypt the download of the torrent. They should not do this unless there is an warrant for an investigation.

> If I don't use encryption, would other users in my LAN or my ISP or other subjects (apart from seeder I download from) be able to discover what I'm downloading or seeding?

Yes. But that is also possible with encryption.

Comment: If the connection is encrypted how can subjects that are not the downloader nor the seeder know what data they're transfering? Is the protocol obsolete? And if they are able to do so, what is the advantage in an encrypted connection against a not encrypted one?

Comment: Opera's VPN will only work on Opera, not for any torrent client unless downloading torrent in Opera itself(unknown if possible).  Need a full system VPN and only have torrent client connect though tun0.

Comment: @crip659 stupid me :D removed it :X

Comment: @Ntakwetet it was never intended to be encrypted; the idea is for all to share with all (and that includes isps and government). https://www.vpnuniversity.com/bittorrent/torrent-clients/qbittorrent-guide  and https://www.vpnuniversity.com/bittorrent/torrent-encryption are good starters on torrents and encryption.

Comment: Unfortunately quite a few people do not know that a browser VPN(extension) does not protect the rest of the OS programs, only what happens in browser.  Think I read of one browser that does do torrents inside of it.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the links, but I'm not trying to encrypt or hide my bittorrent activity, I'm trying to understand what the option actually _does_. I tried to make the question clearer.

Comment: removed th bit about vpn. Again: that option is about who you can connect to. Nothing more.